# Scraping with the normally-fast urllib2 slowed by a number of factors - what are they?

Tags: python, loops, oop, inheritance, list-comprehension

I usually write function-only Python programs, but have decided on OOD approach (my first thereof) for my current program, a web-scraper:

```
import csv
import urllib2

NO_VACANCIES = ['no vacancies', 'not hiring']

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def get_source(self):
        self.source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        return self.source  

class HubPage(Page):
    def has_vacancies(self):
        return not(any(text for text in NO_VACANCIES if text in self.source.lower()))

urls = []
with open('25.csv', 'rb') as spreadsheet:
    reader = csv.reader(spreadsheet)
    for row in reader:
        urls.append(row[0].strip())

for url in urls:
    page = HubPage(url)
    source = page.get_source()
    if page.has_vacancies():
        print 'Has vacancies'
```

Some context: `HubPage` represents a typical 'jobs' page on a company's web site. I am subclassing `Page` because I well eventually subclass it again for *individual* job pages, and some methods that will be used only to extract data for individual job pages (this may be overkill).

Here's my issue: I know from experience that `urllib2`, while it has its critics, is fast - *very* fast - at doing what it does, namely fetch a page's source. Yet I notice that in my design, processing of each url is taking a few orders of magnitude longer than what I typically observe.

- Is it the fact that class instantiations are involved (unnecessarily,
  perhaps)?
- Might the fact that `HubPage` is inherited be at cause?
- Is the call to `any()` known to be expensive when it contains a list comprehension such as it does here?